# Can I revoke some database privileges from MediaWiki after installation?

Tags: mysql, mediawiki

I've just installed MediaWiki on a web server.  Obviously it needs lots of privileges during installation to set up its database correctly.  Now that it's installed can I safely revoke some privileges (e.g. create table, drop table?)  Or might it need to create more tables later (when they are first needed?)  If not then I would prefer to grant it as few privileges as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the installation, MediaWiki doesn't need to create any more tables.  I'd suggest giving the user insert, select, and lock permission.

```
grant select,lock tables,insert on media_wiki_db.* to 'wiki'@'localhost' identified by 'password';
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the user that mediawiki connects as in LocalSettings.php and then using phpMyAdmin, you can edit the privileges of that user (that is, if you aren't comfortable granting and revoking privileges from the mysql console).

http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php

Comment: It already has its own user ('wikiuser'.)  What's the advantage of adding another?

Comment: none, unless you'd used the root user to do it. You can just revoke the privileges for wikiuser with phpMyAdmin and your set.